# Local data that I can't save again gives "UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated" while opening

Tags: pandas, pickle

I have a pandas dataframe that I pickled to backup some data on a server.
Then I imported everything to my local machine using VSCode. Now the server is off and there is no way I can access the data again.

I pickled the data using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
  congestion.to_pickle('/home/tugba/Emissions_Research/DATA2/congestion_sensitivity_short.pkl')
```

However, when I try to open I get the "UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated" error. There is no way I can save the data in another format or generate it again. Most of the solutions that I found suggest saving it in different ways and I can't do that. Is there a way to open this file or some part of it at least?

I tried the below methods and they all have the same error:

```
import pickle
congestion = '/Users/aysetugbaozturk/Desktop/tugba/Emissions_Research/DATA2/congestion_sensitivity.pkl'
with open(congestion, 'rb') as f:  # jupyter notebook saved
    corpus = pickle.load(f)


data_arr = pickle.loads(congestion)
print (data_arr)

congestion  = pd.read_pickle('/Users/aysetugbaozturk/Desktop/tugba/Emissions_Research/DATA2/congestion_sensitivity.pkl')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `pandas.to_pickle()` to pickle a dataframe, you should preferably use `pandas.read_pickle()` to unpickle.